# UIImagePickerController editing image black space on top

Tags: ios8, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm presenting a UIImagePickerController that allow user to edit images, not doing anything fancy here.
Only on iOS 8, if you move the image down there's blank space between the top of the selection box and the top of the picture.

What might be causing it?

[image: Blank space at the top]

Answer (score 1):

It's a well known apple bug... I have found a work around by changing the bool in .plist - View controller-based status bar appearance to 'YES'.

Be aware though, that doing so it'll have you changing any appearance code you have for the statusbar. If your app does not have any, this will be your perfect solution.